# Symfony groups serialization with annotations doesn't work

Tags: symfony, serialization, annotations, deserialization, normalization

**Problem:**

**Symfony is not detecting changes in my annotations code. Every time return same value, with no error response.**

My code:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={"get"},
 *     collectionOperations={},
 *     normalizationContext={
 *          "groups"={"read"}
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $username;
    .
    .
    .
```

Response:

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/User",
    "@id": "/api/users/9",
    "@type": "User"
}
```

Response without normalizationContext{} @ApiResource():

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/User",
    "@id": "/api/users/9",
    "@type": "User",
    "id": 9,
    "username": "admin"
}
```

What's wrong with my code?
I don't know what else I can try to do. Please if you have some advice...
There is no error in response...

**Solved!**
After every change need to clear cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: What you are trying to acheive? How do you know something is wrong? What did you try? Try to add more info to your question and you'll get much more attention.

Comment: Right, thank you, I'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Symfony is not detecting changes in annotations try clearing a cache first by running:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Thank you. This should be mentioned in the document.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved, just reinstalled service serializer!

Comment: The reason why package reinstallation has fixed the issue is because composer runs cache:clear command after install or update

Comment: True, on every change I need to clear cashe. Thank you!